# Ajax request error 419 using radio and form

Tags: html, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to send values from the radio when clicking the button by ajax for a laravel route, however it is returning 419 and I send the token csrf.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#valor").on('click', function()
       {
        $.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "personagem",
    data: 'personagem='+$('input[name="personagem"]').val(),
    success: function(data){
        $(location).attr('href', "{{ URL::to(Request::path()) }}");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro no Ajax !');
    }
}); 
    });
});
```

```html
            
            <div class="col-md-2 name-system">
                <input type="radio" id="system" name="personagem" value="1"/>
                <label for="system"><img src="img/system.png" alt=""></label>           
                <center><span><h3>System</h3></span></center>
            </div>

            
            <div class="col-md-2 name-web">
                <input type="radio" id="personagem2" name="personagem" value="2"/>
                <label><img src="img/web.png" alt=""></label>
                <center><span><h3>Web</h3></span></center>
            </div>  

            
            <div class="col-md-2 name-master">
                <input type="radio" id="personagem3" name="personagem" value="3"/>
                <label><img src="img/master.png" alt=""></label>
                <center><span><h3>Master</h3></span></center>               
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>                  
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" id="valor" name="valor" />

                </div>
```

The variable must be delivered by post to the controller but an error is already occurring in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send the token in your data body request. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#valor").on('click', function()
       {
        $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/personagem",
    data: {
        personagem: $('input[name="personagem"]').val(),
        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    success: function(data){
        $(location).attr('href', "{{ URL::to(Request::path()) }}");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro no Ajax !');
    }
}); 
    });
});
```

Comment: can you see the request response details on your browser devtools > network

Comment: Working,
it was the controller that was not receiving the variable.